# Why it's asking id in newTask. In the tutorial did the same thing but I got this error

Tags: angular

Error: src/app/components/add-task/add-task.component.ts:32:25 - **error
TS2345:** Argument of type '{ text: string; day: string; reminder: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task'.
Property **'id'** is missing in type '{ text: string; day: string; reminder: boolean; }' **but required in type 'Task'.**

32     **this.onAddTask.emit(newTask);**
~~~~~~~

src/app/Task.ts:2:5
2     id: number;
~~
'id' is declared here.

I'm getting above error in my project. Please help

**add-task.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit,Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from '../../Task';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-task',
  templateUrl: './add-task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-task.component.css']
})
export class AddTaskComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onAddTask: EventEmitter<Task> = new EventEmitter();
  id!: number;
  text!: string;
  day!: string;
  reminder: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

    enter code here

  onSubmit(){
    if(!this.text){
      alert('Please Add a Task');
      return;
    }
    const newTask = {
      text: this.text,
      day: this.day,
      reminder: this.reminder,
    };

    this.onAddTask.emit(newTask);

    this.text = '';
    this.day = '';
    this.reminder = false;

  }
}
```

**Task.ts**

```
export interface Task{
    id: number;
    text: string;
    day: string;
    reminder: boolean;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what tutorial you are referring to; but the error and the error message are self-explanatory. You even answered your own question by posting the structure of `Task` - it *has* `id`, but your `newTask` doesn't. So, what's the questiion?

Comment: If you don’t need the id, simply remove it from the interface? Or make it optional like id?: number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make id optional

```
export interface Task {
  id?: number;
  text: string;
  day: string;
  reminder: boolean;
}
```